# git credentials not used

Tags: git, gitlab

In my pipeline I use DVC, and we transfered systems, now something with git clone does not work.

What I have done:

```
echo "https://bot_name:${PROJECT_ACCESS_TOKEN}@gitlab.ourproject.com/team/Data-Registry.git" >> ~/.git-credentials
```

The code interally (dvc.update) does not do a https clone, but a ssh clone:

```
git clone git@gitlab.ourproject.com:team/Data-Registry.git
```

I then get

```
git clone git@gitlab.ourproject.com:team/Data-Registry.git
Cloning into 'Data-Registry'...
git@gitlab.ourproject.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But when I do

```
git clone https://bot_name:${PROJECT_ACCESS_TOKEN}@gitlab.ourproject.com/team/Data-Registry.git
```

it works just fine. Since the whole pipeline is done via dvc.update(), I cannot pass the credentials manually. The pipeline worked on the old system, but I cannot get it to work when setting it up internally.

How can I prepare the credentials so that git@gitlab clone works?

Comment: Does the `PROJECT_ACCESS_TOKEN` environment variable exist?

Comment: I did a `echo "https://bot_name:${PROJECT_ACCESS_TOKEN}@gitlab.ourproject.com/team/Data-Registry.git"`, and it said in the build log [MASKED]. Plus for testing the https:// clone I copied it from my project's Variables. So yeah, it does exist.

Comment: Try `git config --global url.https://gitlab.ourproject.com/.insteadof git@gitlab.ourproject.com`.

Comment: If I do that, it asks me for username and password again. Should I do this instead with "https://user:password@gitlab".insteadOf ? Sounds very hacky, but might work?

Comment: Tried it now in the pipeline, but dvc apparently circumvents this somehow. When I do it in command line, it works, from dvc.update() it did not